# Jquery Cycle Plugin - How to pause slideshow when a pager link is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cycle

I am using the Jquery cycle plugin to create an announcements slideshow. I would like to pause the slideshow when the user clicks on one of the pager links. I have tried using the pagerClick function and attaching the pause function to the onclick event for the pager links, but neither worked. Can you help?

```
$('#highlights')
.after('<div id="pager">')
.cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 4000,
    pager: '#pager',
    pagerEvent:'mouseover',
    activePagerClass: 'active',
    pause: 1,
    pauseOnPagerHover: 1,
    pagerClick:function() {$('#highlights').cycle('pause')}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [pause/resume demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pause.html) you should be able to do:

```
$('#pager a').click(function() { 
    $('#highlights').cycle('pause'); 
});
```

That should bind to the links in your pager.

```
$('#highlights')
.after('<div id="pager">')
.cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 4000,
    pager: '#pager',
    pagerEvent:'mouseover',
    activePagerClass: 'active',
    pause: 1,
    pauseOnPagerHover: 1
});

$('#pager a').click(function() { 
    $('#highlights').cycle('toggle'); 
});
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I tried it already and it didn't work.

Comment: for some reason using toggle works, but not pause. But thats fine with me, it accomplishes the same thing basically.
$('#pager a').click(function() { 
    $('#highlights').cycle('toggle'); 
});

Comment: Interesting. Glad you got it sorted. I'll update my code so that someone finding this question in future will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the pause command worked for me with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#highlights').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade', 
        speed:  'slow', 
        timeout: 4000, 
        pager:  '#pager', 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '#controls a:eq(' + idx + ')'; 
        } 
    });

    $('#pager a').click(function() { 
        $('#highlights').cycle('pause'); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `.stop()` method?

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting pauseOnPagerHover to 0... When you set that to 1, it pauses when you hover over the pager, but also includes a function to play on mouseout.  Therefore your onclick function is pausing an already-paused show, then when your cursor leaves the pager, the mouseout function makes it play again anyway.

I would guess 'toggle' might be working because maybe cycle uses toggle to play and pause in the pauseOnPagerHover function?  You're then pausing on hover, playing on click, pausing again on mouseout.